# Increase LinearLayout width from either right or left

Tags: android, width, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout which is centered on the screen. It has a width less than the screen width. There are two buttons: Right-Arrow and Left-Arrow.
When the user presses the relevant button, the layout should increase its width from the relevant side. The other side should keep its position there.

Right now setting the width increases the layout from both sides equally. The layout needs to be initially centered and it has to expand from either side by user's input. (Use case is to find the width of relevant part of an image whose right and left sides have unequal borders, so the user has to mark them using my technique).

I am using following to increase width but it has the behaviour described above.

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) 
                                      llCropOverlay.getLayoutParams();
params.width = params.width + 1;
```

PS: This functionality was implemented in Tasker app since its early days; so it is possible.

EDIT:
Here is the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llRightLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LEFT" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RIGHT" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/llCropOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@color/colorCropOverlay"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The last LinearLayout (llCropOverlay) should be resized. Note that I am programatically changing the width to 300 before using resizing the buttons so I can test if the buttons are working.

Comment: Post the full layout.  There are ways to do this, but it isn't just a matter of your layout params, but how you're laid out in your parent.

Comment: posted the xml code

Comment: how about instead of changing the width of the layout, you change the margins? `match_parent` + L-margin > R-margin if you want to shift/expand it right. (equal to simulate centered)

Comment: as stated by @TWL just reduce respective sides margin L/R on button press.

Comment: it doesn't work. When I decrease the margin from one side, the layout still starts moving towards that side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an almost perfect solution (there is sometimes a problem with one pixel which is annoying - any suggestions will be appreciated).

For this, we need some variables set up. Firstly, the LinearLayout called llCropOverlay must be found and identified.
Here is its xml:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/llCropOverlay"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@color/colorCropOverlay"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Now before allowing user to interact we need to find the original position of the llCropOverlay. So use this in OnCreate():

```
llCropOverlay.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                orgX = llCropOverlay.getX();
            }
        });
```

Now set up all the buttons and set a setOnTouchListener() on these buttons. Then when the listener is called, pass the touched button in the following method. Use a Handler and postDelayed() to keep calling this method till the button is pressed. Or call it once to resize by one pixel row/column.

```
void handleTouchOrClick(View view) {
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) 
               llCropOverlay.getLayoutParams();

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.bUp:
            params.height = params.height - 1;
            break;
        case R.id.bDown:
            params.height = params.height + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.bRight:
            params.width = params.width + 1;
            llCropOverlay.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    llCropOverlay.setX(orgX);
                }
            });
            break;
        case R.id.bRightContract:
            params.width = params.width - 1;
            llCropOverlay.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    llCropOverlay.setX(orgX);
                }
            });
            break;
        case R.id.bLeft:
            params.width = params.width + 1;
            orgX--;
            llCropOverlay.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    llCropOverlay.setX(orgX);
                }
            });
            break;
        case R.id.bLeftContract:
            params.width = params.width - 1;
            orgX++;
            llCropOverlay.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    llCropOverlay.setX(orgX);
                }
            });
            break;
    }
    llCropOverlay.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Now here's how we actually resize the image:
For ease of users I am cropping it in two steps.

Crop from sides:

```
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =
     (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) llCropOverlay.getLayoutParams();

                    float eventX = params.width;
                    float eventY = 0;
                    float[] eventXY = new float[]{eventX, eventY};

                    Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
                    imageView.getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

                    invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
                    int x = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[0]);
                    int y = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[1]);

                    int height = params.height;
                    while (height * 3 > originalBitmap.getHeight()) {
                        height = height - 10;
                    }
                    croppedBitmapByWidth = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, (int) orgX, 0,
                            x, height);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmapByWidth);
```

crop from bottom:

```
                    float eventX2 = 0;
                    float eventY2 = params.height;
                    float[] eventXY2 = new float[]{eventX2, eventY2};

                    Matrix invertMatrix2 = new Matrix();
                    imageView.getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix2);

                    invertMatrix2.mapPoints(eventXY2);
                    int x2 = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY2[0]);
                    int y2 = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY2[1]);

                    croppedBitmapByHeight = Bitmap.createBitmap(croppedBitmapByWidth, 0, 0, 
                                 croppedBitmapByWidth.getWidth(), y2);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmapByHeight);
```